# react-router-dom typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have typescript error with Switch and Route from react-router-dom and I don't know why they appear. Probably it's because of libraries versions incompatibility, but I did't find information about it.

[Switch type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKFx8.jpg)

[Route type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUT88.jpg)

Libraries versions:

- react: 17.0.1
- @types/react: 17.0.1
- react-router-dom: 5.2.0
- @types/react-router-dom: 5.3.1
- typescript: 4.5.5

UPD. I updated `@types/react-dom` library, because it has old version and added `@types/react-router` library and types errors disappeared.

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a similar scenario, the error message was related to React Router typings, and in the path route you could finde something like */react-router/ts4.6/index.dts*

It seems that the typings have been updated to use a more modern version of TypeScript, in my case I had installed version 3.9, so I just upgraded to the latest TypeScript stable version and the errors went away (of course due to the upgrade got another minor errors in my app that I had to fix).